# Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component even if the app is wrapped around BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to route between 2 paths,
I installed `npm install react-router` (react-router: 6.2.1 and react-router-dom: 5.2.0).

I get a error saying in the webpage `Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.` which eventually meant I din't warp my index.js file with BrowserRouter but I did.

Code:
**index.js**

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router}  from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <Router>
    <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**app.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
  <>
    <Routes>
    <Route path ="/" element={<Main />} />
    <Route path ="gigs" element={<Gigs />} />
    </Routes>
</>
  );
}
```

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue, so I guess the error is somewhere else. Could you please provide a reproducible example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here the mistake between react router version and which version you target to use...

you need to determine which version you like to use, if v6, then you need to follow the v6 rule, if v5 then you need to follow v5...

for example:

```
"react-router": "6.2.1",
"react-router-dom": "6.2.1"
```

Now for the code diff:
in V6:

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />

      {/* Using path="*"" means "match anything", so this route
            acts like a catch-all for URLs that we don't have explicit
            routes for. */}
      <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
```

in V5:

```
    <Router>
<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/dashboard">
        <Dashboard />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

see these links [v6](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/basic?file=src%2FApp.tsx) [v5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/basic)

Comment: $ npm ls react-router
└─┬ react-router-dom@6.6.2
  └── react-router@6.6.2


$ npm ls react-router-dom

└── react-router-dom@6.6.2

Above are my versions. My code looks exactly like your v6 but am still getting the error.

Comment: isset imported like this: import { Routes, Route, Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";
can you validate this https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dev/examples/basic/src/App.tsx?

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you are specifying two different versions. The router you are using is from v5, but the `Routes` and `Route` components are expecting a v6 router providing a specific v6 context.

If you are using `react-router-dom` version 6 components then you need to use version 6 of `react-router-dom`. You can remove `react-router` since `react-router-dom` re-exports these components.

From the project directory run the commands:

1. Unintall `react-router` and `react-router-dom`

   `npm uninstall -s react-router react-router-dom`
2. Install `react-router-dom` version 6

   `npm install -s react-router-dom`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you don't need to wrap your `Routes` component in a React Fragment. It also seems that it might cause problems with react router [as mentionned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67140467/react-router-routes-not-working-using-a-fragment).

Also I would either add a `/` in front of `gigs`, or nest the `gigs` route in the `/` route.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrapp your component in this way instead

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
<React.StrictMode>
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
);
```